# Angular Material Datepicker get string instead of object toString

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've created an Angular shared component representing an Material Datepicker.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'm6smart-form-datepicker',
  templateUrl: './form-datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-datepicker.component.scss'],
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormDatepickerComponent), multi: true,},],
})
export class FormDatepickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() formInput!: FormDatepickerInput;

  onChange: any = () => {};
  onTouch: any = () => {};
  value: string | undefined;
  disabled: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}
  writeValue(obj: any): void {this.value = obj;}
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {this.onChange = fn;}
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {this.onTouch = fn;}
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: any): void {this.disabled = isDisabled;}
}

<mat-form-field (click)="picker.open()" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>{{ formInput.label }}</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [required]="formInput.required" disabled autocomplete="off" />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker disabled="{{ formInput.disabled ? formInput.disabled : false }}"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

After creating an 'UntypedFormGroup', I included my component in an Angular page. While the component itself works fine, I am facing an issue when trying to retrieve the values from the form.

Instead of getting the formatted date that I see in the input field, I'm getting the date object's 'toString' value (ex: Wed May 10 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200).

I've looked online and in the documentation for a solution, but most of them rely on the deprecated Moment.js library. Could you suggest a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using date-fns. It is much more versatile than moment.js and well supported:

https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started

You can then use the format function:

https://date-fns.org/v2.30.0/docs/format

Example:

const result = format(this.formInput.value, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
//=> '05/09/2023'

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping that we could make some changes to the component so that it returns the accurate value.